# I can't make the post or put with fetch or axios to the swagger-ui API to create a login page

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, fetch, swagger-ui

I am trying to make a login page with react using a swagger api: this is the code that i have but it give me this error: POST https://dev.tuten.cl/TutenREST/rest/user/testapis%40tuten.cl 400 (Bad Request)

when i make the test in the API, it gives me an ok, but with my function the result it's 400 BAD REQUEST i can't understand why it's not working:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

```
const onSignIn = async ({ email, password, app }) => {
    const result = await fetch('https://dev.tuten.cl/TutenREST/rest/user/testapis%40tuten.cl', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
            app,
        }),
    });
    if (result.ok) {
        const promiseData = await result.json();

        console.log(promiseData);
    } else {
        console.log('Access is not allowed');
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the actual stacktrace from the backend?

Comment: Hello, no sir, I can't, i don't have access to the backend

Comment: The doc page on the screenshot uses PUT not POST. Are you supposed to use PUT instead?